# LaplaceTransform doesn't work

Tags: functions, symbolic, integral-transforms

I have code:

```
A = 1;
ω0 = 5*10^6;
τ0 = 3*10^-3*Sqrt[2/Log[2]]/(5.85*10^3);
s0[t_] = A*E^(-t^2/τ0^2)*Cos[ω0*t];
Phi[ω_] = LaplaceTransform[s0[t], t, ω]
```

The last string doesn't execute correctly (it just return this string unexecuted). What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The functional form of your ``s0`` is $a e^{-bt^2}\cos(ct)$. Therefore, you can try calculating the Laplace transform with parameters and substitute values afterwards: ``Clear[a, b, c]; phi = LaplaceTransform[a Exp[-b t^2] Cos[c t], t, w, Assumptions -> {a, b, c} \[Element] PositiveReals]`` returns ``(a E^(-((c + I w)^2/(4 b))) Sqrt[\[Pi]] (1 + E^((I c w)/b) (1 - I Erfi[(c - I w)/(2 Sqrt[b])]) + I Erfi[(c + I w)/(2 Sqrt[b])]))/(4 Sqrt[b])``. Then, use ``phi /. {a -> A, b -> 1/τ0^2, c -> ω0}``

Comment: Which version of Mathematica? Did you start from a new kernel? It works for me.

Comment: Include `TrigToExp`, i.e., `Phi[ω_] = LaplaceTransform[s0[t] // TrigToExp, t, ω]`

Comment: `LaplaceTransfrom` dosen't like non-exect numbers.Try: `LaplaceTransform[Rationalize[s0[t], 0], t, \[Omega]]`